# Eclipse Node debugging : Source locator does not exist ChromiumSourceDirector

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

Version: Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20160913-0900

I was working on my Nodejs project, happily able to debug into a JS script; then I installed the Angular eclipse plugin, and since then whenever I try to launch the debugger for my JS script, I get an error window:

> Launching STANDALONE_V8 has encountered a problem.
>
> Source locator does not exist:
>
> org.chromium.debug.core.ChromiumSourceDirector

I tried:

1. uninstalling the Angular components
2. deleting the .metadata dir from my workspace

But the Node Debugger still won't launch as it used to.

Any other suggestions?